# Ring Homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am confusing myself here.

Also, is it always understood that we are considering unital ring homomorphisms?

$\phi(r)=\phi(\sum_1^r 1)= \sum_{i=1}^r \phi(1) = r \phi(1) = r(0+30 \mathbb{Z}) = r \cdot 30\mathbb{Z}$

Something is wrong here since I know it should be the projection homomorphism, so I should have $r+ 30 \mathbb{Z}$.

Also if I drop this unital homomorphism are there others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require unital ring homomorphisms, then you have $\phi(1)=1+30\mathbb{Z}$, not $\phi(1)=0+30\mathbb{Z}$ as you've written in your question. Then the rest of your work is correct,
$$r\phi(1)=r(1+30\mathbb{Z})=\underbrace{(1+30\mathbb{Z})+\cdots+(1+30\mathbb{Z})}_{r\text{ times}}=(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{r\text{ times}})+30\mathbb{Z}=r+30\mathbb{Z}$$
If you do not require ring homomorphisms to be unital, then you can have a homomorphism $\phi$ send $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ to any $k+30\mathbb{Z}$ as long as $k^2 -k \equiv 0 \bmod 30$.

Comment: I am so stupid. I needed to be considering the multiplicative identity of the quotient ring, no the additive.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us sometimes :)

Comment: Sorry, thanks for catching that.